# How to establish uniqueness of atoms that satisfy Prolog predicate?

Tags: prolog, uniqueidentifier, quantifiers

I want to represent in a knowledge base that `foo(X)` for only one value of `X`.  Basically, a statement that `foo(X), foo(Y)` implies that `X \= Y`.  But Prolog insists on backward chaining, or an "is implied by" relation.  I don't know how to code that.

Comment: What you really mean to say is that you want to ensure you don't have any redundant facts, `foo/2`. But what do you want in terms of a Prolog query? Perhaps, `unique_facts(foo)` would succeed if your requirement is met? I'm not sure what you mean when you say you *want a knowledge base that...*.

Comment: You can say `foo(value)` if you know the value.

Comment: It gets a little messier... when you have `foo(X), foo(Y)` in Prolog, the second call will start from the beginning of the database of asserted facts, so even if you have only `foo(a).` asserted, the expression *`foo(X), foo(Y)` implies `X \= Y`* would be false. If you were checking for uniqueness of facts, you could determine that the facts were unique by checking for duplicate results in a `findall(X, foo(X), Foos)`.